# Fetch nested query parameters in URL

Tags: asp.net, url, c#-4.0, query-string

I have a URL which which has a query parameter that itself contains a query string with other parameters. E.g:

https://discovery.com/disco.ashx?entityId=www.test.com&return=https://myidp.com/?param1=myvalue

How do I get the value of the nested param1?

I have tried something like this but it doesn't work:

```
var returnParam = context.Request.QueryString["return"];

var test = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(returnParam);

var value = test["param1"];
```

Comment: What do you get for `returnParam`, `test`, and `value`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this - `var u = new Uri(returnParam); var newparams = u.Query;`

Answer (score 0):

`HttpUtility.ParseQueryString` expects only the query string as input.
Extract the query string from the url using `Uri` and then pass that to `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString`

```
var uri = new Uri(Request.QueryString["return"]);
var queryParams = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query);
var value = queryParams["param1"];
```